# Match any symbol in Bash case statement

Tags: bash

I have a string of pattern `<digit>, <digit>`. I want to check whether it has:

- Two zeroes
- Left zero and right non-zero
- Left non-zero and right zero
- Anything else

I have tried to do this with the following code:

```bash
case ... in
    "0, 0") ... ;;
    "0, ?") ... ;;
    "?, 0") ... ;;
    *)      ... ;;
esac
```

But it is only matching "two zeroes" and "any other" cases. How can I fix that?

Comment: Now you're checking for literal `?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the interpretation of the [globs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), they must be outside of the double quotes:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in

  "0, 0")  echo case 1 ;;
  "0, "?)  echo case 2 ;;
   ?", 0") echo case 3 ;;
  *)       echo default ;;

esac
```

Examples:

```
$ b.sh "0, 0"
case 1
$ b.sh "0, 1"
case 2
$ b.sh "3, 1"
default
$ b.sh "3, 0"
case 3
```

If you want to match only digits, "?" glob is too permissive as it matches any char not necessarily a digit:

```
$ b.sh "a, 0"
case 3
```

To be more restrictive, intervals can be used to match only digits:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in

  "0, 0")      echo case 1 ;;
  "0, "[0-9])  echo case 2 ;;
   [0-9]", 0") echo case 3 ;;
  *)           echo default ;;

esac
```

Comment: Is this the only way to do what I want? It looks bad, comparing to regexp-like `0, .` and `., 0` where I don't need to take `?` outside.

Comment: case/esac does not use regexp but globs. The latter is less powerful than regexp used in sed command for example. Some more details about case/esac statement in bash: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-case-statement/

Comment: I you want to make sure to match digits instead of any chars with "?", you can use intervals: "[0-9]" is one digit from 0 to 9. But stil outside of double quotes! I updated the answer...